# Product gets removed from mini-cart even if I click "Cancel" on confirm pop-up

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, mini-cart

When I click to remove product from mini-cart a confirm dialog pops up with "Cancel" or "Ok", if I click on "Cancel" the product still gets removed.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

This is the `a` element to remove product from mini-cart:

```
<a href="long_delete_url_here" title="Remove This Item" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?');" class="btn-remove">Remove This Item</a>
```

No errors in console, tried adding custom jquery function, adding preventDefault, but nothing. Even just adding `onclick="return false;"` doesn't do anything.

I did a small test and added `onclick="return false;"` to different elements like buttons and links in different templates, but the buttons and links still work after clicking on them. Any idea what could be wrong?

Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: Are you using the default magento mini cart or some other ajax mini cart.?

Comment: @AthulVijayan default.

Comment: @AthulVijayan I did a small test and added `onclick="return false;"` to different elements like buttons and links in different templates, but the buttons and links still work after clicking on them. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Remove This Item" onclick="productcartremove(event);" class="btn-remove">Remove This Item</a>


<script>

        function productcartremove(event,url) {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?");
        if (r == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It still removes the product (the link fires anyway).

Comment: This is working fine on my magento instance.